# rails 3, rules pluralization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created an application in Rails, I want to create a puccuentas model:

```
rails g scaffold puccuenta numero:integer pucgrupo_id:integer nombre:string
```

the output console is:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20110819163754_create_puccuentas.rb
  create    app/models/puccuenta.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/puccuenta_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/puccuentas.yml
   route  resources :puccuentas
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/puccuentas_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/puccuentas
  create      app/views/puccuentas/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/puccuentas/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/puccuentas/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/puccuentas/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/puccuentas/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/functional/puccuentas_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/puccuentas_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/unit/helpers/puccuentas_helper_test.rb
```

my file inflection.rb

```
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
   inflect.plural /puccuenta$/i, '\1puccuentas'
   inflect.singular /puccuentas/i, '\1puccuenta'
 end

when entering the url http://localhost:3000/puccuentas

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PuccuentasController#index

Mysql2::Error: Table 'proyecto_development.puccuenta' doesn't exist: SELECT `puccuenta`.* FROM `puccuenta`
Rails.root: /home/andres/desarrollos/rubyonrails/proyecto

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/puccuentas_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

I can see that the table is puccuenta, but I have defined pluralize puccuentas. What is the reason for the inflectors failure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try
`inflect.irregular 'puccuenta', 'puccuentas'`

or create a regular one which is flexible, like
`inflect.plural /^(a)$/i, '\1s'`

Comment: the number one indicate the total words ? example

   inflect.plural /ciudad$/i, '\1ciudades'
   inflect.singular /ciudades/i, '\1ciudad'
   inflect.plural /^(a)$/i, '\1s'
   inflect.singular '\1s', /^(a)$/i,
   inflect.irregular 'puccuenta', 'puccuentas'

Comment: the number indicates the match. So if you have `/(puccu)e(nt)(a)/` then `\1 = "puccu"`, `\2 = "nt"` and `\3 = "a"`

Comment: ah, yes, the restart thingy, always forget this